# Service discovery (Spring cloud - Eureka) and Routing(Zuul) in Elastic beanstalk

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I am trying to develop a spring cloud micro service using spring and spring cloud. And I would like to deploy my micro service application in AWS elastic beanstalk. I have doubt in including Spring cloud tools in my micro service.

- Whether Elastic beanstalk provide service discovery and routing like spring cloud Zuul when i am taking a Elastic beanstalk account, Or I need to implement those all with my micro service implementations?

When I am exploring Spring cloud micro services, I found that eureka and Zuul spring cloud tools. Then I added eureka server and registered my spring boot micro service as a client to eureka server. And also added the Zuul for routing. But I have still confusions in adding spring cloud in my micro services and for deployment.

- When I deploying my current micro services, I need to deploy all spring boot applications(1-eureka server, 2- Micro service , 3- Zuul)?? Or Elastic beanstalk will provide all services(Means I only need to deploy my micro service and elastic beanstalk will provide service discovery routing services for spring cloud)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic beanstalk won't provide service discover or routing. It will only ease the devops work. You still need to have discovery service and zuul as dockerized containers.

You can use AWS Elastic Beanstalk(EB) or EC2 Container Service(ECS) for microservices deployment.

If you want to control your scaling and capacity use ECS, ECS will give you control, as you have to specify the size and number of nodes in the cluster and whether or not auto-scaling should be used.

If you want to focus on the app and not much on DevOps use Elastic Beanstalk. For Elastic Beanstalk just provide a Dockerfile and EB takes care of scaling your provisioning of number and size of nodes, you basically can forget about the infrastructure with the EB route.